# What does the exception : "Service provider invocation failure" mean? and what is the commonly known fix for this?

Tags: sabre

I am trying to make a call for PriceQuoteService by importing new WSDL. There was an error while I tried to make the call where the auto-generated code of WSDL contained [][] instead of []. Upon making necessary replaces I am getting "Service provider invocation failure". I could not find mention of this error in all related documents. 
I would like to know the cause and likely fix for this.

Comment: Can you post request & response please? Yeah Sabre is notoriously incorrect with their WDSL